# Why does reading a non-blocking socket return an error status code

Tags: c, file-descriptor

After successfully reading a socket set up as non blocking, the socket becomes temporarily unavailable. All data is received already with the first `read` call, but the error return value persists for about 5 seconds. After that `read` returns 0 and the socket is once more available.

Why does the socket return the error in the first place?

Set up non blocking socket:

```
/* Non blocking */
int flags = fcntl(sockfd, F_GETFL, 0);
fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
```

Read socket and print:

```
result = read(sockfd, response + bytes_read, RESPONSE_SIZE - bytes_read);
printf("%d | %d | %s\n", (int)result, errno, strerror(errno));
printf("%d | %d | %d | %d | %d | %d | %d | %d \n",
            EAGAIN, EWOULDBLOCK, EBADF, EFAULT, EINTR, EINVAL, EIO, EISDIR);
```

Which results in:

```
152 | 115 | Operation now in progress
11 | 11 | 9 | 14 | 4 | 22 | 5 | 21 

-1 | 11 | Resource temporarily unavailable
11 | 11 | 9 | 14 | 4 | 22 | 5 | 21
```

Comment: Even if it's non-blocking, failing to get data is an error, which is why you get the `EWOULDBLOCK` in `errno` and the `-1` returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no data available in a non-blocking file of a FIFO or socket type, a read will fail with -1 and set errno to `EWOULDBLOCK`. An alias to this `errno` code is `EAGAIN`, which signals you to try again (later, after more data has been entered).

The `0` return value from a `read` on a socket indicated that an end-of-file condition was meant (which means, for a socket, that a shutdown occurred).

From read(2):

> (zero indicates end of file)
>
> ...
>
> On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately.

Answer (score 4):

When a socket is set up as non-blocking, if there is nothing to read the `read` function will return -1 and set `errno` to either `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK`.  That's how you know there's there's nothing to read, at which point you can do other things before trying again.

If `read` returns 0, that means end-of-file was hit, or for a socket that a shutdown happened.